# How do I resolve this bug in d3 js while applying .ticks() to my x scale

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts

I've provided a working example and 2 data sets, one that works correctly, the other that doesn't display the proper graph. I am using a .ticks() function on my x axis and ran into this problem. I want to display all labels as in the working example on the x axis.

https://jsfiddle.net/q0yhobs4/

This is part of the code inside the fiddle.

```
let correctData={
2004: 226.933,
2005: 222.807,
2006: 221.869,
2007: 223.978,
2008: 218.385,
2009: 217.668,
2010: 216.061,
2011: 214.631,
2012: 214.053,
2013: 213.845,
2014: 206.436,
2015: 209.915,
2016: 214.51,
2017: 220.605,
2018: 222.128,
2019: 223.075
}
let asd = Object.keys(results)
    asd = asd.map(item => parseInt(item))
    x.domain(
      d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.year;
      })
    );

svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(asd.length));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your code and found that `asd` and `results` count is not 10 NOT 16. I think the issue is here.

Comment: Yep, the data is the problem. The years are not consecutive in the bad data set.